# Build error in Unity 5

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm an absolute beginner in programming and I'm trying my hand at Unity 5, but I get this error code whenever I try to build this code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour 
{
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);

        Rigidbody.AddForce(movement);
    }
}
```

I get the "error cs0120 an object reference is required for the nonstatic field method or property" can anyone help me out with this one?

Thx!

Comment: Is the error pointing to a specific line of code?

Comment: Sorry, pointing to the last code line.

Comment: `GetComponent<RigidBody>().AddForce(movement);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Previous to Unity 5, "rigidBody" was a property of `GameObject`. Your code still wouldn't have compiled, it would have needed to be:

```
gameObject.rigidBody.AddForce(movement);
```

Because `rigidBody` isn't a property or field of `MonoBehavior`, `gameObject` is. Since its not in Unity 5, you'll need to use `GetComponent`:

```
RigidBody rb = GetComponent<RigidBody>();
rb.AddForce(movement);
```

See the documentation for more: [Unity Docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-rigidbody.html)

When its all said and done, the code would be:

```
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);

        RigidBody rb = GetComponent<RigidBody>();
        rb.AddForce(movement);
    }
```

Comment: I'm still getting the error even after doing everything as told. What is this reference the IDE is talking about? Could  you post how the code would look like after finished?

Comment: @MiguelMelo You are getting that same error? The error means you tried to access a property or method that doesn't exist on the implicit `this` reference. Did you try `gameObject.GetComponent`? I don't remember that being necessary, but I don't have Unity on this machine to try it on .

Comment: Sadly as I told you, I'm a beginner so I don't grasp all the format and syntax properly yet. My code ended being really close to yours, but after the addforce(movement) statement I repeated the rigidbody.addforce(movement) statement.

Comment: @MiguelMelo I thought you might not have realized you needed to *replace* your last line with my supplied sample :)